# Laravel Dusk Select CSS Variable

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-dusk, browser-testing

I'm writing a browser test for my dark-theme. I'm trying to test that when the checkbox is checked, the variable `var(--bg-color)` is `#3a3c3b`. Now when I run this test it always succeeds even if I put some random stuff in the assert value.

```php
    public function DarkTheme()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/')
                ->check('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]')
                ->assertAttribute('', 'var(--bg-color)', '#3a3c3b');
        });
    }
```

Comment: you should set `--bg-color` and not `var(--bg-color)`

Comment: @TemaniAfif nope, that didnt work, the test still came back as OK even when I used a random value.